# Apache 2.4 Date Expressions

Tags: apache, date, expression, local, expr

Pre Apache 2.4 I could write this

```
<!--#config timefmt="%Y%m%d %T" -->
<!--#if expr="($DATE_LOCAL > 20170311 00:00:01) && ($DATE_LOCAL < 20170316 00:00:01)"-->
Show this text during the specified Date/Time
<!--#endif-->
```

I have tried several different ways....but I can't seem to get this to work in Apache 2.4.

I can get it to work if I turn the "SSILegacyExprParser on" ....however I would like to get this working without turning that on in Apache 2.4.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok....I was able to figure this out....and seemed to test fine in Apache 2.4

```
<!--#config timefmt="%Y%m%d %T" -->
<!--#if expr="(v('DATE_LOCAL') > '20170311 00:00:01') && (v('DATE_LOCAL') < '20170316 00:00:01')"-->
Show this text during the specified Date/Time
<!--#endif-->
```

Comment: Documentation says to use `%{"varname "}`,  but only the above `v('varname')` worked for me.